# How to prove that every Lie group is the semidirect product of a connected Lie group and a discrete group?

Tags: lie-groups

> Every Lie group is the semidirect product of a connected Lie group and a discrete group.

I think the component of the identity could be useful.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Show the connected component you described is a normal subgroup first.

Comment: Someone edited my question. I want to show that every Lie group is the semidirect product of a connected Lie Group and a discrete group

Comment: Please edit your question appropriately. There was no version which said something about a semi-direct product.

Answer (score 3):

**Warning.** Apparently the proof is not correct. I will update it later.

For every topological group $G$ with identity component $G^0$ it is well-known and easy to prove that $G^0$ is a normal, in fact characteristic, closed subgroup. If $G$ is locally connected, $G^0$ is open, which implies that the quotient group $G/G^0$ is discrete. The Lie algebra of $G$ is isomorphic to the Lie algebra of $G/G^0 \times G^0$, hence these Lie groups are locally isomorphic. It is not hard to see that the isomorphisms glue to a global isomorphism, since the decomposition into a product of a connected and a discrete Lie group is essentially unique.

By the way, the corresponding statement for topological groups is wrong.

Comment: What about, for example, $O(2n+1)$?  As a manifold, it's diffeomorphic to $SO(2n+1) \times \mathbb{Z}/2$, but not as a group (since $O(2n+1)$ has trivial center but $SO(2n+1)\times \mathbb{Z}/2$ doesn't).  Or am I missing something stupid?

Comment: Why does $O(2n+1)$ has trivial center? If your counterexample is correct, you should add it as an answer (or "anti-answer" ;)).

Comment: Ha!  I got it backwards.  $-I \in O(2n+1)$, and in fact $O(2n+1)\cong SO(2n+1)\times\mathbb{Z}/2$ (as Lie groups).  On the other hand, $O(2n)$ is not Lie isomorphic to $SO(2n)\times\mathbb{Z}/2$.  For example, when $n=1$, $SO(2)\times\mathbb{Z}/2$ is abelian, but generally reflections and rotations don't commute.  (I'm not going to add this as an aswer because the OP has now added a correction asking for a semi-direct product instead of direct product.  I'm not sure how to prove it.)