# Does the projection from a compact Lie group to its component group split?

Tags: lie-groups

This is an elementary question that probably admits an elementary counterexample, but ...

Let $G$ be a compact Lie group and $G_0$ its identity component. One then has a short exact sequence
$$
1 \to G_0 \to G \to \pi_0(G) \to 1;
$$
the last object is the *component group*.

**Does the component group embed as a subgroup?**

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/941066/lie-group-decomposition-as-semidirect-product-of-connected-and-discrete-groups

Comment: I should have thought to search for "semidirect." Thanks.