# The group is a product of its connected component and a discrete subgroup

Tags: general-topology, lie-groups, topological-groups, fiber-bundles

Let $G$ be a Lie group and let $G^0$ be the identity component. It is known that $G^0$ is open and closed in $G$ and that $G/G^0$ is discrete. My question: Is it true that $G=G^0\times G/G^0$? Or equivalently, is the principal bundle $G\to G/G^0$  trivial?

Comment: See: https://mathoverflow.net/a/124622

Comment: @GabeConant What do you think about  this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/q/316386 ?